# evaluate my php code

Tags: php, profiling

Ive write a PHP app which copy some pictures from a public website, but it runs pretty slow. I'll like to see where I have a bottleneck, or where the most times is spent. How can i do that?

I'm using Eclipse PDT as IDE. Are any plugins for it?

Comment: Most likely, more time is spent contacting the server and waiting for a response than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You should try xdebug:  http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

And here is a documentation about PDT and xdebug: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/documents/XDebugGuideForPDT2.0.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Usually code to read/copy data from other servers will cause bottle neck. You can use below code to measure time for some parts of your code then figure it out

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

// your slow code here...

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "$time elapsed\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Webgrind for detecting bottlenecks https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind
Its an web interface for XDebug profiling.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, Xdebug is complex to install, configure, use (in eclipse), but it is powerful once you understand it.

On the client side, in Firefox, try Firebug; or in Chrome, try the Chrome developer tools to determine which elements of the web page need most time to load. Might be simple I/O problem if you're using high-resolution embedded images on your site, or network contacting times as a commenter suggested.

Comment: I appreciate ur replay and your right about that xdebug is difficult to install. I've tried once for 4h and I didn't make it run. I don;t know how to use Firebug, when it is about PHP code. FirePHP is an option but it doen't run on my machine setup after 30minutes of tries.